# Algebraic numbers with a polynomial property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

In my research I faced with an intricate construction of an algebraic number with some properties.

**Problem.** *For which classes of polynomials $P(X,Y)\in \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$, we have the following property. Let $\theta$ be an algebraic number, then there exist an $n$-degree real algebraic number $\gamma$ for which
$$
P(r\gamma,\alpha)\neq \theta,
$$
for all (but finitely many) rational numbers $r$ and all (but finitely many) algebraic numbers $\alpha$ with degree at most $n-1$.*

I can prove this for polynomials of the form $P(X,Y)=F(X)G(Y)$ or $F(X)+G(Y)$, but not for other classes. I believe that this holds for any non-constant (in both variables) polynomial $P(X,Y)$.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Suppose that $P$, $\alpha$, $\gamma$, and $\theta$ are such that $P(r\gamma,\alpha)=\theta$ for infinitely many $r$, that would mean that $P(X,\alpha) = \theta$ as polynomials (since only a constant polynomial can take the same value infinitely many times). This implies that $Y-\alpha \mid P(X,Y)-\theta$. This can only happen for finitely many $\alpha$ by the unique factorization property for polynomials.

Comment: @R.P.  Thank you for your reply, but in the first part you are considering that there exists infinitely many $r$ for a same $\alpha$. This is not necessary, so maybe we have infinitely many distinct pairs $(r_i,\alpha_i)$ for which $P(r_i\gamma,\alpha_i)=\theta$, for all $i$. Am I missing something?

Comment: My apologies, then I have misunderstood the question. There are a lot of quantifiers in your question, it looks like I didn't process them correctly. :-)

Comment: No problem, thank you very much for the interest. Maybe I could write it better :-)

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646448/algebraic-numbers-with-special-properties

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Yes, this was my previous question to deal with particular classes of polynomials $P(X,Y)$ in an attempt to solve the general case.

Comment: There might be a link with the Mordell conjecture here. Suppose that $P(X,Y)-\theta$ is irreducible over $\bar{\bf Q}$. If you restrict yourself to algebraic numbers $\alpha$ in a fixed number field $F$, then if $P(r\gamma,\alpha)-\theta=0$ for infinitely many pairs $(r,\alpha)$ (where $\alpha\in F$), then the non-singular model of the curve over $\bar{\bf Q}$ defined by $P(X,Y)-\theta$ must be of genus $0$ or $1$ by the Mordell conjecture (the theorem of Faltings). That genus can be computed explicitly in terms of $P(X,Y)$ and $\theta$. This is true for any fixed algebraic $\gamma$.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thank you Damian. I thought about this before, but since $\alpha$ belongs to the set of algebraic numbers of degree at most $n-1$ I cannot apply this beautiful result.